# Struggling to understand the logic of interacting with my MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Firstly, sorry in advance for asking a question that I know has been answered elsewhere - it's just that I've tried for hours and hours to transfer what they say into my own program, and always hit the same snags. I figured that the best way to solve it is to just ask my own question.

#### The Project

I'm working on a booking form in which parents of absent children can sign their kids out of school. The idea is that it saves the year group assistants constantly taking calls saying someone's going to be absent, and adding it to a calendar - if a program took care of that, then they can focus on their other important roles in regards to relations etc.

So, I made a HTML form:

[image: HTML Form]

Once someone fills in the form, and presses Submit, an object is created:

```
class Teacher
{
    constructor(TeacherObject)
    {
        this.Tutor = TeacherObject.Tutor;
        this.YearGroup = TeacherObject.YearGroup;
        this.FullName = TeacherObject.FullName;
        this.ID = TeacherObject.ID;
    }
}

class Student
{
    constructor(Teacher, StudentName)
    {
        this.StudentForm = Teacher;
        this.StudentName = StudentName;
    }
}

class Request
{
    constructor(Student, Dates)
    {
        this.AbsentStudent = Student;
        this.AbsenceDates = Dates;
    }
}
```

A 'Request' object is created with all the necessary information, and the idea is that the information within is then passed onto MySQL to be added to a database.

#### The Problem

From what I understand, PHP is server-side and runs before any Javascript/jQuery/HTML code. If the code which adds the data into the database is in PHP, then this surely must run before the rest of the code which creates the object to add to the database? If I use `include()` or `require_once()` then all the code within the PHP file I specify runs before I get the chance to give it any of the data, which comes at the 'end' of the program, so to speak.

I read about AJAX, from what I understand you can, like, *wait* to run the PHP code or something? If that's what I'm missing, would someone be able to explain how I would use it?

I've set up a function within the PHP file:

```
function addData($requestDataInJSONFormat)
{
    echo "Just testing....";
}
```

but surely if it's all run before the rest of the page loads, then how can I 'wait' until I have the final student object, to pass to the PHP function and add it to the database? I'm so confused!

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems that you understood your problem, PHP is a server-side language, which means that it's run by the server, and the server is then giving the browser an html page ( basically ).

Which means that you can pass a php variable to a javascript one for example :

```
...
var javascript_var = <?php echo $php_var; ?>;
...
```

But about your question, you will have to use AJAX to "talk" to the server without having to go to another page. Remember when you create a basic form in php, you send the datas to a php file which is then doing all the back-end stuff ( saving it into the db etc... )

AJAX will let you do the same ( sending datas to a php file, could be something else ) without reloading the page ( this is the Asynchronous in AJAX ).

So you have to write a php file, which will save your datas in your database. And use AJAX to send datas to this page from the front-end.

So AJAX is no magic, it's not gonna talk with your database directly, it will just allow you to run a php file without actually making the user leave the page to go on your register.php file.

I won't give you the code here since there is a lot of tutorials out there, but you can start by looking at this link :

https://www.sanwebe.com/2016/01/ajax-registration-script-using-jquery-with-php-and-mysql

It's pretty much what you intend to do from what I understood.

Hope I could make it clearer for you,

Cheers,